# Does the Data Lake Storage Gen2 Path - Create API support concurrent execution?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

We are working to upload the files to ADLS2 storage. However, the context path of files can be the same. For example:

1. basePath/parent/path1/file1.json
2. basePath/parent/path1/file2.json

We have been using the following API to create the file at the specified path: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create. However, the API doesn't talk about how two parallel operations to create the different files at the same directory location are handled. Since, the API also creates the directory as well, we wanted to ensure it accounts for concurrency before running concurrent requests.

Currently we are working with only a single file creation and we wanted to ensure it accounts for concurrency before running concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you cannot create multiple files at the same time in Azure Data Lake Gen2 using a single REST API call. However, you can use multiple threads to create files concurrently. Each thread can create a file using a separate REST API call.

Alternatively, you can try exploring Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics pipelines. These services provide built-in support for parallelism and can handle multiple concurrent requests to create files.

If you have any additional feedback for the product team, would encourage you to please log it here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/a8bb4a47-3525-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f84